# Connect two SQL-tables and order the result by a group

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

1. main-table (table1) with the fields ID and name
2. detail-table (table2) with the fields ID, id_main, group, details1, details2, ...

There is to say, that in the detail table there could be multiple entries (with the same id_main), which belongs to a single unique entry of the main table. So I try to get as a result for every entry of the main table, every entry of the detail table (which belongs to that id) grouped by the group-field.

I tried this

```
SELECT 
    t1.id as id1, 
    t1.name as name,
    t2.id_main as id2,
    t2.group as group,
    t2.detail1 as detail
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_main
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you don't need a `group by` at all.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display a heading for each group, like in a report viewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    t1.name,
    t2.group,
    t2.detail1 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_main
ORDER BY t2.group
```

Keep in mind that in the result pane of your SQL engine you will get the `group` field in all the rows that this applies to. If you want to display it like a report, then you should use a reporting tool, such as Crystal Reports or SSRS.

Comment: I do not know what is your problem. Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05e74/3 on your example. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: You probably need to quote `group` because that is a reserved word: `"GROUP"`

Comment: And i would also add that using reserved names for user defined objects such as tables or columns is not a good option.